# Pandas - Export of dataframe's header and index to Excel causes TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am using `pandas 0.15` and `openpyxl 2.2.0` as writer engine, but the same problem occurs with `pandas 0.16`.

I need to export a pandas dataframe to an `.xlsx` file. The dataframe is very simple - something like:

```
   col_A  col_B col_C
0      1    100    AB
1      2    200    AC
2      3    300    AD
```

I can export the dataframe's content (i.e. without index labels and column names):

```
df.to_excel(path_to_xlsx_file, sheet_name, header=False, index=False)
```

However, if I include either index labels or column names (or both), I get a TypeError. This:

```
df.to_excel(path_to_xlsx_file, sheet_name, header=False, index=True)
```

or this:

```
 df.to_excel(path_to_xlsx_file, sheet_name, header=True, index=False)
```

causes this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-a60810c2c9c2>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('F:/mine/python/pandas_tests.py', wdir='F:/mine/python')

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 601, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 66, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "F:/mine/python/pandas_tests.py", line 25, in <module>
    df.to_excel(path_to_xlsx_file, sheet_name, header=True, index=False)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1260, in to_excel
    startrow=startrow, startcol=startcol)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 705, in write_cells
    xcell.style = xcell.style.copy(**style_kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.0-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\styles\styleable.py", line 107, in style
    protection=self.protection

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.0-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\styles\__init__.py", line 42, in __init__
    self._font = font

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.0-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 35, in __set__
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(self.expected_type))

TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fonts.Font'>
```

I can't use xlsxwriter as the dataframe must be exported to an existing file.

Comment: Cannot replicate. Works perfectly for me. Python 2.7.x and Pandas 0.16

Comment: which python package are you using? i'm running python(x,y) 2.7.9.0 on a windows 7 64-bit machine.  Can the problem be related to OS or python package I use?

Comment: fall back to previous version of openpyxl (2.1.3) solved the issue

Comment: 2.1.5 is the most recent in the 2.1 series. Could do with a bug report to help track this down but I suspect it's down to the new handling of styles, though strict typing has been around for a while.

Comment: I also had this problem and thanks to snowlion i did 

pip install openpyxl==2.1.3

to fall back to a previous version, so that I can now export to excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use openpyxl version 2.1.3 or 2.1.5.